# Apple Thunderbolt 2 to FireWire adapter

Tags: 17.04, apple, adapter, thunderbolt, firewire

I want to use an Apple Thunderbolt 2 to Firewire adapter. It's connected through an Apple Thunderbolt 3 to Thunderbolt 2 adapter. Ubuntu seems not to recognize the Firewire adapter out of the box.

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 17.04
Release:    17.04
Codename:   zesty

uname -r
4.10.0-19-generic

sudo lshw -short
H/W-Pfad                 Gerät     Klasse         Beschreibung
===============================================================
                                    system         Z170N-Gaming 5 (Default string)
/0                                  bus            Z170N-Gaming 5
/0/0                                memory         64KiB BIOS
/0/3d                               memory         16GiB Systemspeicher
/0/3d/0                             memory         8GiB DIMM DDR4 Synchron 2133 MHz (0,5 ns)
/0/3d/1                             memory         Project-Id-Version: lshwReport-Msgid-Bugs-To: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>POT-Creatio
/0/3d/2                             memory         8GiB DIMM DDR4 Synchron 2133 MHz (0,5 ns)
/0/3d/3                             memory         Project-Id-Version: lshwReport-Msgid-Bugs-To: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>POT-Creatio
/0/43                               memory         128KiB L1 Cache
/0/44                               memory         512KiB L2 Cache
/0/45                               memory         3MiB L3 Cache
/0/46                               processor      Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-6100T CPU @ 3.20GHz
/0/100                              bridge         Skylake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
/0/100/1                            bridge         Skylake PCIe Controller (x16)
/0/100/1/0                          display        Oland GL [FirePro W2100]
/0/100/1/0.1                        multimedia     Cape Verde/Pitcairn HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 7700/7800 Series]
/0/100/14                           bus            Sunrise Point-H USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
/0/100/14/0              usb1       bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/14/0/6                       input          USB Gaming Keyboard
/0/100/14/0/d                       communication  Bluetooth-Schnittstelle
/0/100/14/1              usb2       bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/14/1/5            scsi6      storage        Storage Media
/0/100/14/1/5/0.0.0      /dev/sdb   disk           15GB Storage Media
/0/100/14/1/5/0.0.0/0    /dev/sdb   disk           15GB 
/0/100/14/1/5/0.0.0/0/2  /dev/sdb2  volume         15EiB Windows FAT Laufwerk
/0/100/16                           communication  Sunrise Point-H CSME HECI #1
/0/100/17                           storage        Sunrise Point-H SATA controller [AHCI mode]
/0/100/1b                           bridge         Sunrise Point-H PCI Root Port #17
/0/100/1b.2                         bridge         Sunrise Point-H PCI Root Port #19
/0/100/1b.3                         bridge         Sunrise Point-H PCI Root Port #20
/0/100/1c                           bridge         Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #1
/0/100/1c/0                         bridge         DSL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Alpine Ridge 4C 2015]
/0/100/1c/0/0                       bridge         DSL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Alpine Ridge 4C 2015]
/0/100/1c/0/1                       bridge         DSL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Alpine Ridge 4C 2015]
/0/100/1c/0/2                       bridge         DSL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Alpine Ridge 4C 2015]
/0/100/1c/0/2/0                     bus            DSL6540 USB 3.1 Controller [Alpine Ridge]
/0/100/1c/0/2/0/0        usb3       bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/1c/0/2/0/0/1                 generic        Thunderbolt 3 (USB-C) to Thunderbolt 2 Adapter
/0/100/1c/0/2/0/0/2                 input          USB Optical Mouse
/0/100/1c/0/2/0/1        usb4       bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/1c/0/4                       bridge         DSL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Alpine Ridge 4C 2015]
/0/100/1c.2                         bridge         Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #3
/0/100/1c.3                         bridge         Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #4
/0/100/1c.4                         bridge         Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #5
/0/100/1c.4/0            enp13s0    network        Killer E2400 Gigabit Ethernet Controller
/0/100/1c.5                         bridge         Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #6
/0/100/1c.5/0            wlp14s0    network        Wireless 8260
/0/100/1c.6                         bridge         Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #7
/0/100/1c.7                         bridge         Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #8
/0/100/1d                           bridge         Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #9
/0/100/1f                           bridge         Sunrise Point-H LPC Controller
/0/100/1f.2                         memory         Memory controller
/0/100/1f.3                         multimedia     Sunrise Point-H HD Audio
/0/100/1f.4                         bus            Sunrise Point-H SMBus
/0/1                     scsi4      storage        
/0/1/0.0.0               /dev/sda   disk           480GB TOSHIBA-TR150
/0/1/0.0.0/1             /dev/sda1  volume         511MiB Windows FAT Laufwerk
/0/1/0.0.0/2             /dev/sda2  volume         438GiB EXT4-Laufwerk
/0/1/0.0.0/3             /dev/sda3  volume         8068MiB Linux swap Laufwerk
/1
```

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: I think this is worth a bug report. My guess: there's no driver support for this in Linux because (1) it's an uncommon set-up that draws little kernel developer attention and (2) Apple doesn't care about Linux or FireWire (any more).

Comment: Linux does not recognize FireWire from out of the box since kernel 2.6.37 Source: https://ieee1394.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Video1394

Comment: @V-Mark Do you know how to enable the adapter?